# use of getId() & setId() in mage_core_model_abstract

Tags: model, save

I want to understand functions of mage_core_model_abstract.

For this I'm using Mage::log() function in different places.

and I'm using custom module with model.

I'm thinking getId() & setId() functions will call If i save new record in db or update exist record of model in the process of save() function.

But in magento log i'm not getting any values.

For example my custom module with 3 fields(entity_id(primary key & auto increment),field1,field2).
and I have 3 records like this

1 apple yellow

2 flower green

3 fruit  red

If i edit first record & save I should get $object->getId() value "1" In

> Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract::save(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
>   $object).

If I add new record magento should pass "4" value to  $object->setId($id).

please look at line `$object->setId($this->_getWriteAdapter()->lastInsertId($this->getMainTable()));`
Am i correct?

update:
following updated successfully.Normally everyone using load($id) function.

```
 $_book = Mage::getModel('namespace_module/mydata');
$_book->setId(7)->setField1('85')->setField2("jkl")->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento doesn't define the next `entity_id` value as it auto increments, MySQL will set this when you save a new object - thus you won't see a call to `setId()`.  You also won't see a call to `getId()` when loading the object as it's done in the format:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('module/model')->load($id);
```

so you need to know the id of the model before you load it - either that or you filter the collection by other parameters to select the correct model.

If you instantiate a model with just:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('module/model');
```

and then `save()` it you will enter a new row into the table of interest and on save and the `entity_id` of this new row will be populated into the model as it's id as it didn't exist before.  If you instantiate a model with instead:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('module/model')->load($id);
```

this will pull an existing row from the database table according to the id you specify, in this case when you save, as the id is already in the object, the relevant row in the relevant table is instead updated.  So the key here is the existence of an id in the instantiated model object, no id = new entry is saved vs id exists = existing entry is updated.

The only time you are going to see a call to the `getId()` or `setId()` methods of an object if is some code dealing with the object after it's loaded calls it, you won't see it during the standard load or save process.

And by the way, you are calling `getId()` and not just `getId`?

Comment: yes i'm calling getId().please look at once.i updated.

Comment: The call to `setId()` in `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract::save` is used to assign the id of the row just saved in the case of saving an new object as I put above.  Can you describe what exactly it is you are trying to do, loading the model without `load()` and instead setting the id before save, although it will work is not good practice.

Comment: Now i'm able to log the values(problem i was not enabled default configuration previously).I'm seraching for answer  "How does Magento figure out if a
save()
 call needs to create an INSERT or an UPDATE query?"

Comment: That's in my answer too - if an id exists in the object already the query will be an update, if no id exists in the object the query will be an insert. The presence of an id on the object is the key.